# SQL similar a busca (search) do dataTable

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Estou querendo  criar um sql que faço uma busca similar ao framework [dataTable](https://datatables.net/)

percebi algumas regras na busca:

1. se eu busco por 1 palavra ele me retornar os resultados que contém essa palavra
2. se eu busco por 2 palavras ele me retorna a string que possuí essas 2 palavras (pode ter outras palvra contida na string, mas tem q conter as duas)
3. se eu busco por 3 palavras ele me retorna a string que possuí essas 3 palavras (pode ter outras palvra contida na string, mas tem q conter as 3)

e assim por diante... o que deu para entender é que so traz o resultado aquela string que contem as palvras citadas na busca

ja tentei usar o like e o MATCH(nome) AGAINST($string), porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Basta você adicionar um `and campo_tabela ilike '%cada_palavra%'` para cada palavra da pesquisa na consulta. Se você informar qual é a linguagem de background e como está o seu código atual com a tentativa de criação da consulta iria facilitar bastante te responderem.

Comment: Obg, fiz da forma q vc mencionou... deu ok

Comment: add como resposta q darei como certa!

Comment: Disponha, você mesmo pode responder a questão, poderia até dizer na resposta qual foi a linguagem e a forma que usou essa linguagem para separar o texto em palavras para usar na query.